# Mixed CocoaPods project: ObjC functions are visible from Swift, class variables are not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have set up a Swift iOS project with CocoaPods. I want to use pods based on both Swift and Objective C. Let's say I want to use `KeychainAccess` (Swift-based) and CocoaLumberjack (Objective C-based). Here's the `Podfile` I use:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'KeychainAccess'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
```

Now, I try to use these pods:

```
import UIKit
import KeychainAccess
import CocoaLumberjack

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this works fine
        let keychain = Keychain(service: "access-token")

        // this works as well
        DDLog.addLogger(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance())

        // 'DDLog.Type' does not have a member named 'logLevel'
        DDLog.logLevel = .Verbose
        // 'DDLog.Type' does not have a member named 'logAsync'
        DDLog.logAsync = false
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? How do I make `CocoaLumberjack` work? (or any other ObjC pod, I assume I will have the same issue with other pods as well).

I have created a [project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25100182/CocoaPodsPlayground.zip) which reproduces this issue.

Comment: Looks like lumberjack is still working on swift support. Can you tell me the version number of lumberjack that you have installed? It might require you to set an explicit release for swift support (pod 'CocoaLumberjack' ~> '2.0.0-rc2'). There is a discussion on github here https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/405

Comment: @gjeck I can't check at the moment, I think it is a stable version, 2.0.0 (not a release candidate). Anyway, do you mean that this issue is specific for CocoaLumberjack?

Comment: Yea it's really up to each project to be compatible with the new use_frameworks! feature in Cocoapods. It looks like CocoaLumberjack has a branch "swift_support" that should be compatible. The project milestones indicate there should be full Swift support by "2.1.0". So for now point to the swift branch.

Comment: @deville Alternatively as a temporary workaround you might want to make an Objective-C object that wraps the CocoaLumberjack calls and provides your Swift access. Unfortunately you'll lose useful log information like Calling Function, File, and Line Number.